# why my UINavigationbar is hidden?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, xcode-storyboard

I'm working on an ios app.
My problem is that on my storyboard I have a navigationbar that is shown, but when I run the application, it is hidden and i dont know why....

First I have a "StartViewController" that loads the data and shows the MainViewController, I do it like that :

```
 - (void)finishDownloadDataWithError:(NSError *)error{
//si il ya pas eu d'erreur on arrête la video et on éxecute loadMainView.
if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"download OK");

    //simule un téléchargeemnt de 3s
    //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.f];
    _loadingIndicator.hidden = YES;


}
//si il ya eu des erreur on affiche la popup d'erreur.
else {
    NSLog(@"download fail");


}
//on utilise ce booléen pour être sur de ne créer qu'une seul fois les instances des controllers
static BOOL firstTime = YES;
if (firstTime) {
    firstTime = NO;

    //chargement de la vue suivante
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    MainViewController * controller = (MainViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

  }

}
```

Here is my MainViewController

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


self.navigationBar.title = @"FoodStash";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

}

Here is my storyboard :
[image]

[image: here the simulator without my navigationbar !!!!]

Here is the simulator without my navigationbar !!!!
Can you help me please ?

**UPDATE**
i try this, but my mainviewController dont appear now.

```
 //chargement de la vue suivante
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *naviCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];
  [self presentViewController:naviCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Check if `self.navigationController` is nil.

Comment: he is nil... what is the best way to initialise it ? and where ? in my startviewcontroller ?

Answer (score 1):

I got your issue.

Please check Navigation Controller as **is initial view controller**

[image]

After that your `ViewController` set as `RootViewController` like below screenshots

This is your result:

[image]
  [image]

And set a identifier for HomeView controller "HomeID"

when u navigate:

```
 -(void)MOve_screen
 { 
   HomeViewController *home = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeID"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];

 }
```

If any doubt u can fell free to ask me :)

Comment: it works almost, the navigationbar is showed on the startviewcontroller. but the navigation bar isnt showed on the mainviewcontroller

Comment: ya see my app its showing perfectly on all view controller

Comment: now it works good ;)
just need to hide navigationbar when startview is loaded , and show it before to show the mainview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide storyboard id to your navigationController in your storyboard, namely "navigationController" and you need to add below lines.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];   
UINavigationController *naviCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NAVIGATION_CON_ID"];
// [naviCon addChildViewController:YOUR_VIEW_CON_OBJ];   //no need of this lines as your navigation controller is connected with your VC so it will automatically show your VC. 
[self presentViewController:naviCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So now you would have access to your navigationController from storyboard and also your navigation bar.

Comment: i do it but,the navigationcontroller is not loaded, the app stay on the starviewController.

Comment: Did you debug to check if you reach to line of codes of jumping from star VC to navigationCon

Comment: Coudl you update your query with your latest code that u have used.

Answer (score 0):

Since you show your `MainViewController` with:

```
 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It's a fullScreen view showed with a modal and not a push a segue, maybe you should consider embedding your first view in a navigation controller and use push segues.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller  animated:Yes];
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how I solved my problem.

[image]

in startviewcontroller after downloadingdata :

```
    - (void)finishDownloadDataWithError:(NSError *)error{
             [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.f];
            //si il ya pas eu d'erreur on arrête la video et on éxecute loadMainView.
            if (error == nil) {
                NSLog(@"download OK");

                //simule un téléchargeemnt de 3s

                _loadingIndicator.hidden = YES;


            }
            //si il ya eu des erreur on affiche la popup d'erreur.
            else {
                NSLog(@"download fail");


            }
            //on utilise ce booléen pour être sur de ne créer qu'une seul fois les instances des controllers
            static BOOL firstTime = YES;
            if (firstTime) {
                firstTime = NO;


                 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;

                MainViewController *home = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];

            }

        }
```

in startviewcontroller again :

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    }
```

in my mainViewController :

```
        - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

           self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
            self.title = @"FoodStash";

           }
```